# VBA : Overflow error in multidimensionnal array init

Tags: excel, vba

I got a bizzare overflow message error with this code and I can't understand why. 
Could you please help ? I am using exactly the same code in another vba module and it works.

```
Dim tab_base As Variant
tab_base= Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:AL1492").Value
```

Thanks,

Ismail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have some invalid cells in the range. I suspect mostly some cells formatted as `Date` with a value that is either too large or negative.

To be on the safe side and get the numeric values independent of the format, use the recommended `.Value2`. So try

```
tab_base= Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:AL1492").Value2
```

Then you get everything in the array as either strings or numbers (for date: number). You can later convert numbers to dates if necessary, but you can also check them for errors before.

For example, before converting some cell to a date, something like this:

```
Dim d As Date
On Error Resume Next
d = tab_base(i, j)
if Err.Number <> 0 Then ' invalid date, this was a cell causing overflow
```

p.s.: check for example if `Err.Number = 6`, it means you really had a date overflow (thx Mat's)

Comment: Technically that comment is only valid when `Err.Number = 6` ;-)